# Compilation failed: POSIX collating elements are not supported at offset

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match-all, regex-group

i would like transform a string to array with pattern. But my regex give me the warning.

this is a string:

```
$string = typ="bar" title="Example" enabled=true count=true style="float: left; width: 30%;"
```

My regex:

```
$regex='/(.*?)[=\"|=](.*?)\"*\s*/';
preg_match_all($regex, $string1, $matchesreg, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Whith the regex is the output not correct. The last array must be split further
    $regex='/(.*?)="(.*?)"\s*/';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string1, $matchesreg, PREG_SET_ORDER);
The output

```
Array
     (  
         [0] => Array
             (
                 [0] => typ="bar" 
                 [1] => typ
                 [2] => bar
             ) ...
         [2] => Array
             (
                 [0] => enabled=true count=true style="float: left; width: 30%;"
                 [1] => enabled=true count=true style
                 [2] => float: left; width: 30%;
             )    
     )
```

My desired output like:

```
php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => typ="bar" 
            [1] => typ
            [2] => bar
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title="Example" 
            [1] => title
            [2] => Example
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => enabled=true
            [1] => enabled
            [2] => true
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => count=true
            [1] => count
            [2] => true
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => style="float: left; width: 30%;"
            [1] => style
            [2] => float: left; width: 30%;
        )    
)
```

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('~([^\s=]+)=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))~', $s, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)`, see https://3v4l.org/hJcmW

Comment: Thank you. This is probably the right regex. I will test it tonight in my function further.

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you. If my answer turned out helpful please consider upvoting it, too (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Comment: At noon today, the vote did not want. Just on another computer it worked. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_match_all('~([^\s=]+)=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))~', $s, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/hJcmW)

**Details**

- `([^\s=]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and `=`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))` - a branch reset group matching either of

  - `"([^"]*)"` - `"`, then any 0 or more chars other than `"` are captured into Group 2, and then `"` is matched
  - `|` - or
  - `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score -1):

Your expression seems to be working fine. There were two `=` in your char list that I removed one of them:

```
(.*?)[=\"|](.*?)\"*\s*
```

You can modify/change your expressions in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ETCPdl/1), if you wish.

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Code

```
$string1 = 'typ="bar" title="Example" enabled=true count=true style="float: left; width: 30%;';
$regex = '/(.*?)[=\"|](.*?)\"*\s*/s';
preg_match_all($regex, $string1, $matchesreg, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_dump($matchesreg);
```

#### Output

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "typ=""
    [1]=>
    string(3) "typ"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "bar" "
    [1]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "title=""
    [1]=>
    string(5) "title"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Example" "
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Example"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "enabled="
    [1]=>
    string(7) "enabled"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "true count="
    [1]=>
    string(10) "true count"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "true style=""
    [1]=>
    string(10) "true style"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that matches the OP's desired output?